# Android Studio not creating the .apk file when imported a project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have imported a project into android studios 3.1.1 which is using android google maps api. When I am running the project it is not creating the .apk file for the project so that I can test it in my phone. It works fine with the emulator but it is not creating the app.apk file in the output

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It **must** have created the `.apk file` for it to **run** on the emulator !

Answer (score 0):

If for some unknown reason this is true, here is a way to do this yourself in one button click.

[This is the image to know where to click!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRYL3.jpg)

And here is the path you need to select if you do not see the image:
On the top menu part click on *Build* --> *Build(APKs)*.

After the process finish you will be able to find the APK here:
`YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER\app\build\outputs\apk\debug`